# Extend base type and automatically update audit information on Entity

Tags: c#, algorithm, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I have an entity model that has audit information on every table  (50+ tables)

```
 CreateDate
 CreateUser
 UpdateDate
 UpdateUser
```

Currently we are programatically updating audit information.

Ex:

```
  if(changed){
        entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        entity.UpdatedBy = Environment.UserName;
        context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

But I am looking for a more automated solution.   During save changes, if an entity is created/updated I would like to automatically update these fields before sending them to the database for storage.

Any suggestion on how i could do this?  I would prefer to not do any reflection, so using a text template is not out of the question.

A solution has been proposed to override SaveChanges and do it there, but in order to achieve this i would either have to use reflection (in which I don't want to do ) or derive a base class.  Assuming i go down this route how would I achieve this?

For example

```
EXAMPLE_DB_TABLE
 CODE
 NAME
 --Audit Tables
 CREATE_DATE
 CREATE_USER
 UPDATE_DATE
 UPDATE_USER
```

And if i create a base class

```
 public abstract class IUpdatable{

     public virtual DateTime CreateDate {set;}
     public virtual string CreateUser { set;}
     public virtual DateTime UpdateDate { set;}
     public virtual string UpdateUser { set;}
 }
```

The end goal is to be able to do something like...

```
   public overrride void SaveChanges(){
        //Go through state manager and update audit infromation
        //FOREACH changed entity in state manager
        if(entity is IUpdatable){
           //If state is created... update create audit.
           //if state is updated... update update audit
        }
   }
```

But I am not sure how I go about generating the code that would extend the interface.

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer, but I've done something similar with LINQ to SQL.  Check out my blog post http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2009/05/auditing-inserts-and-updates-using-linq.html.  It might give you some ideas.  The basic idea is to extend the data context and override SubmitChanges and do the audit work there.  My audit information is stored in a different table and I audit both success and failure so it uses a separate context, but you may still get some ideas from it.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking into doing some code gen stuff using .tt files, but i was hoping for something simpler, ill read it tonight and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the final solution.

I basically check my model for the presence of 4 properties.  If the entity contains

InsertedOn and InsertedBy and UpdatedOn and UpdatedBy I generate (using a tt file) the following entity that implements an IAuditable interface.

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    void SetInsertedOn(DateTime date);
    void SetInsertedBy(string user);
    void SetUpdatedOn(DateTime date);
    void SetUpdatedBy(string user);
}

public partial class ExampleDBtable: EntityObject, Audit.IAuditable
{
     //Normal EDMX stuff here..
     public static ExampleDBtable CreateExampleDBtable(int id, string code, string name, DateTime insertedOn, string insertedBy, DateTime updatedOn, string updatedBy)
       {

       }
       //Extension points.
    #region IAuditable Members

    public void SetInsertedOn(DateTime date)
    {
        this._InsertedOn = date;
    }

    public void SetInsertedBy(string user)
    {
        this._InsertedBy = user;
    }

    public void SetUpdatedOn(DateTime date)
    {
        this._UpdatedOn = date;
    }

    public void SetUpdatedBy(string user)
    {
        this._UpdatedBy = user;
    }

    #endregion

    }
```

I also generate code to handle the updating of audit information

```
   public ExampleDBObjectContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "publicExampleDBObjectContext")
    {
        this.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(UpdateAuditInformation);
        this.OnContextCreated();
     }
```

And then finally I implemented the UpdateAuditInformation

```
   foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
            context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
        {
              //Start pseudo code..
              if(entry.Entity is IAuditable){
                 IAuditable temp = entry.Entity as IAuditable;
                 temp.SetInsertedOn(DateTime.Now);
                 temp.SetInsertedBy(Env.GetUser());
                 ...

              }
        }
```

I opted not to show the .tt file because it looks horrible in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can do something like this. The general idea would be

1. Handle [ObjectContext.SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx).
2. In that event, call [ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738497.aspx)(EntityState.Modified)
3. Iterate the results and set properties if needed.

Comment: "Iterate the results and set properties if needed." scares me... you suggesting reflection?

Comment: No, I'm not. Go through each modified entity and look at its type. If it's one you want to audit, set `entity.UpdatedOn`, etc.

Comment: Which unless they all extend some interface you would have to do reflection ?

Comment: I would pick an interface. But no, it's not the only choice. You can test the type and then cast, too.

Comment: How would I make all entities extend the base class (which would contain the audit fields)?  In all honestly i don't know how to map this in the edmx..

Comment: Like I said, I'd pick an interface. You don't change the EDMX. You add interface support in a partial class you create.

Answer (score 0):

Look to [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp). Very nice solution for such tasks.

Comment: any chance you could give me a little more...  i am guessing the idea is i tag my properties with trace attributes>?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, didn't see your question.

There is a possibility to define one assembly-wide Trace attirubute.

Comment: Yeah Right. There's no sample's on that, only text that it might be used for that..

Answer (score 0):

Is it not simpler to 'stamp' the updated rows via database triggers? Are the information provided in the database not adequate enough? (database user vs. os user)

Comment: we can't get the right user, we pull it from the calling context, or we would use triggers.